# Bounced emails check

Tags: python, arrays, list, smtp

I'm writing a program that checks which email addresses have bounced (not delivered) and generating a list for that in Python. But so far, I only get the bounced emails in the first page of Inbox (from what I understood from my code). Here's what I have so far:

```
inbox = {}

for item in items:

# getting email content
resp, data = M.fetch(item, "(RFC822)")
email_content = data[0][1]

msg = email.message_from_bytes(email_content)
content_list = msg.as_bytes().decode(encoding='UTF-8').split('\n')

# retrieve email address sent out
for cl in content_list:
    if cl.startswith('To: '):
        inbox[cl.replace("To: ", '').strip()] = 1
    #print(cl) this prints out the sent email addresses

fail_content = ['Delivery Status Notification (Failure)','Undeliverable:','DELIVERY FAILURE:','Returned mail:','Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender']

# check Inbox
M.select('INBOX')
resp, items = M.search(None,"All")
items = items[0].split()
#print(items) prints out the number of inbox emails

for item in items:
resp, data = M.fetch(item, "(RFC822)")
email_content = data[0][1]
msg = email.message_from_bytes(email_content)

# check for all possible fail content
for fc in fail_content:
    if fc in msg['Subject']:
        # get email content
        content_list = msg.as_bytes().decode(encoding='UTF-8')
        # find its sender
        for eo in inbox:
            if eo in content_list:
                inbox[eo] = 0

print(inbox)
```

Comment: Is this the exact indenting you used in your actual code? Because I noticed your for loops don't have indents

Comment: @TheGrandJ No, I'm very new to Stackoverflow. When i copied over the code, it messed up the indentation.

Comment: Could you make it match? Because When I look at it now I am tempted to say it's just that your item for loop doesn't actually loop and hence will probably only get 1 result